# Recompense for taanis chalom on day with double keduasha

Tags: shabbat, fast-days, yom-tov, rosh-chodesh-new-month, dream

A person is permitted to perform a taanis chalom (fast for having a bad dream) on shabbos, but is supposed to fast a second time to compensate for having fasted on shabbos (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 288).

My question is if a person performed a taanis chalom on a day which has two reasons to prohibit from fasting such as shabbos which is also rosh chodesh or shabbos which is also yom tov, does such a person have to perform 2 additional fasts as recompense, or is only 1 fast sufficient?