# If one fasted on Shabbos, is he obligated to fast another day?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, fast-days

If one fasted on Shabbos, is he obligated to fast another fast in addition to the fast that he fasted on Shabbos?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36863 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, s/he does. See [Berakhot 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.31b.24), [Orach Chayim 288:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%97_%D7%93), [Mishnei Torah Taaniyot 1:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/951995/jewish/Taaniyot-Chapter-One.htm#v12). Though one should only fast if s/he had a disturbing dream.

Comment: There are several different opinions, caveats, and alternatives mentioned in the poskim regarding performing such a *ta'anis chalom* on Shabbos in the first place, and many poskim go to lengths to discourage it in the great majority of cases. With regards to the additional compensatory fast on Sunday if someone indeed fasted on Shabbos, however, the halacha is more straightforward that it is necessary (although if it is difficult to fast on that Sunday, or if there is a reason to prohibit fasting on that Sunday, one may be able to make up the compensatory fast on another day - Sh"A OC 288:4).

Comment: @Fred  does the person have to accept the fast on shabbos in order for the fast to count on sunday?

Comment: @Fred if he wasn't m'kabel the additional fast on  Shabbos itself, like one is supposed to do, and he fasted on Sunday, would he still be yotzei his obligation to fast for fasting on Shabbos?  And if he is not yotzei his obligation with that fast, would he be patur from fasting altogether since the whole week after Sunday he isn't allowed to fast because of Chanukah?

Comment: @tomelpora [CYLOR](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/594). A *ta'anis chalom* doesn't have to be accepted in advance, but I'm not sure about the compensatory fast on Sunday. My guess is it doesn't have to be declared in advance because 1) the default obligation would be to fast on Sunday (unless the person doesn't feel up to it or there is some need to postpone), 2) I'm not sure re the propriety of declaring a fast on Shabbos for the following day, and 3) according to Rav YD Soloveitchik, the role of the compensatory Sunday fast itself is that it serves as a more proper *ta'anis chalom*

Comment: @tomelpora Take what I'm saying with a grain of salt, as I haven't researched this recently. It seems correct, however, that a person should not make up the fast on Chanuka under any circumstance (Rama OC 288:4), and if one did so, he would then have to fast a third time to compensate for fasting on Chanuka (MB 288:9)!

Comment: @Fred i know he woudn't fast on chanukah, but i was wondering if chanukah cancels the fasting obligation altogether

Comment: @tomelpora The Taz (288) implies that a person's obligation for the compensatory fast lasts through Yom Kippur, after which the obligation would lapse if it hadn't yet been fulfilled (although some acharonim indicate that even after Yom Kippur one would have to make up the fast). Seemingly, one would fast after Chanuka if one didn't get around to fasting before Chanuka.

Comment: @Fred ok thanks.  as you mentioned before, do you think the fast to penalize one for the fact that he fasted on Shabbos is obligatory, and thus he presumably wouldn't need to be m'kabel the fast on  Shabbos itself for the Sunday fast to count toward his obligation?

Comment: @tomelpora First of all CYLOR, and if you still have multiple questions that may be relevant for a wider audience, consider posting them as separate questions!

Comment: @tomelpora Seems like a reasonable conclusion. The wording of the gemara and poskim (especially the Shulchan Aruch) suggests the make up fast is obligatory. However, I agree with the comment from Kazi-bácsi.

Comment: What if you don't like eating food?

Comment: @tomelpora Yours is a complex question that may hinge on the nature of this make-up fast. (1) Is קבלת תענית במנחה on the prior day necessary for a post-*ta'anis chalom* compensatory fast, or is mentally accepting it during or after mincha time on Shabbos sufficient (see MB on 563), or does it not require any קבלה like a ta'anis chalom itself (Rama 562, MB 562:26)? (2) It's not clear that one would fast the make-up *l'chatchila* on Erev Chanuka (MB 686:1), and even if one does, it's unclear whether one should continue fasting after sunset through *tzeis* (cf. MB 249:23 in tension with 288:14).

Comment: R' Yosef Yuzpa Kashman (18th c., Frankfurt) commented ([*Noheig Katzon Yosef*, כ"ד כסליו](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8905&st=&pgnum=179)), based on the sefer יוסף אומץ (where his grandfather [R' Yosef Yuzpa Hahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Yuspa_N%C3%B6rdlinger_Hahn) of Frankfurt comments that a person who fasts on Erev Chanuka may or should break the fast before lighting), that a person should not undertake (for Erev Chanuka) any fast that they would be required to complete through nightfall. Per the MB (249:23), an ordinary *ta'anis chalom* should extend to nightfall

Comment: @Fred ok thanks.